# What type return executeFetchRequest

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I'm trying to get an entity from `CoreData`:

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Themes")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)
        if results.count > 0 {}
```

But I'm getting `error '[AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'count'`
How can I access each entity in results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results` is an optional, which means you first need to unwrap it. Try using like this:

```
if let results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) {
    if results.count > 0 {}
}
```